# What is the reason for these weird white shadows on a printed shirt?

Tags: print-design

There are some textures applied to the design, to make it look distressed. The effects are transparent and should "blend" into the shirt. 
Any idea, what the problem is? And if anyone knows how these white shadows are called.

Edit: the shirt was printed with DTG technology, if this helps.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that t-shirt is just old and faded

Comment: @Cai, the shirt is of course brand new.

Comment: You can also buy brand new jeans that are ripped and faded and look like they have been dragged through rubble

Comment: @Cai, i'm fully aware of that. I thought it was obvious that I made this shirt and I'm wondering why was there a problem with the print.

Comment: Oh... In that case I completely misunderstood the question. Apologies!

Comment: Did you actually print the shirt yourself or did you have it produced for you? Are you using a white base to print? It looks like a white base and either a problem applying the ink or a problem in curing

Comment: Nope, the design of the shirt was uploaded to one of those "upload and sell" t-shirt websites. I ordered one for myself. :/

Comment: Oh! in that case I would use another service.. not much you can do about it really. Assuming you sent them a single color image they just messed up

Answer (score 3):

It was probably printed in white first and then in black over it. This is usually done to print **light colors on dark shirts** and still have them appear bright. In case of printing black it's obviously unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but It is not clear what the problem is. Take a new photo without the flash, stand next to a window without direct sunlight. I do not know if I am seeing reflections, if the shirt has a white base.

But a basic problem could be that the worker did not apply enough ink, or pre-spreaded the ink into the silk even and smooth.

I am stealing this comment from Cai: "It looks like a white base and either a problem applying the ink or a problem in curing"

A list of problems could be:

- The ink is contaminated and do not stick properly (missuse of solvents, old ink)
- The operator did not spreaded the ink evenly or did not performed a pre-pass.
- The ink is not compatible with the base ink (if there is one)
- The ink did not cured properly (solvent related, humidity, temperature)
- Wrong mesh, the mesh is too tight for the thickness of the ink.

Comment: No, there are no reflections, I'm guessing the transparent parts of the design did not print well. You can see a big white blob on the letter F in the word "for". The white stuff should be transparent.

Comment: Could also be that the screen hasn't been degreased properly or the ink wasn't prepared properly or the wrong mesh count was used or probably a bunch of other stuff

Comment: Or since the update to the question (the print is actually DTG) a lot of this is irrelevant :p

Answer (score 0):

If this is thermal transfer printing then it will look like this on any shirt that is not either white or black. And each one of them require different transfer film for that particular color. This white noise would be not noticeable on white shirt but on grey it is visible.

The way to solve this would be to not use any other way of blending apart from black to 0. Think of using a stencil more then printing a gradient.